# How to create a color picker in html?

Tags: html, colors, colorbox, color-picker

How to make a color picker, like we see in different websites where users can scroll down different colors and on click can get the color code?

I have tried of making a rows and columns but it was not so comfortable so want it to be like a color picker

You can take a look at the color box how i am trying it to be:

[image]

I have gone through different questions but I'm not able to solve this issue.

Comment: I've made a simple [color-picker](https://github.com/yairEO/color-picker), it's actually not that hard! just math, the key is using *HSLA*

Answer (score 23):

## Option #1 - Native HTML Color Picker

As mentioned in the previous answers you can use Native HTML color picker element:

```html
<input type="color" />
```

For more info see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color

## Option #2 - 3rd party Color Picker

If the Native color picker not meet your criteria, since it has an obsolete look and not look as slick as modern Color-Pickers, you can use one of literally hundreds of color pickers on the web. Even a simple search on the NPM packages page will return a few hundreds results to pick from.
https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=color%20picker

## Option #3 - Build your own Color-Picker

If you like me, and after a long search of color-picker library, you didn't find a picker that meet your criteria, you can build you color picker, which not take too long as I will demonstrate.

1. Find a Color-Wheel image that will be your picker, for example:
    (a more complex colors-wheel probable needed in real application)
   [image: color wheel]
2. In your .html file, create a `canvas` element.

```html
<canvas id="colorCanvas" class="color-canvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
```

3. Give the canvas element `border-radius: 50%`, this will make the canvas round, so only clicks inside the circle will be fired, and clicks in the edge will be ignored (we will need click event in the next steps).
4. In your JavaScript, init the canvas with your color-picker image, and listen to click events

```js
function initColorPicker()
{
    var canvasEl = document.getElementById('colorCanvas');
    var canvasContext = canvasEl.getContext('2d');

    var image = new Image(250, 250);
    image.onload = () => canvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height); 
    image.src = "./images/myColorPickerImage.png";

    canvasEl.onclick = function(mouseEvent) 
    {
      var imgData = canvasContext.getImageData(mouseEvent.offsetX, mouseEvent.offsetY, 1, 1);
      var rgba = imgData.data;

      alert("rgba(" + rgba[0] + ", " + rgba[1] + ", " + rgba[2] + ", " + rgba[3] + ")");
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but the 3rd option won't work for me.(Tried with .php and .html)

Comment: @Momoro, I don't know what was your exact solution, but my solution is a pure client side solution, it doesn't need any PHP or other server side coding.

Comment: I had already known that it didn't need PHP or server side coding, I was testing it on other formats.

Comment: Okay, for example, I choose first option #1, how to get color from user chose variant?

Comment: @NNL993 As you can read in the API: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_color.asp Use the `value` property to set/get the selected color

Answer (score 16):

You can simply create a color picker by `<input>` with type as color. But it works only in modern browsers.

```html
<input name="Color Picker" type="color"/>
```

Comment: I think most so called modern browsers don't support

Comment: This is a nice answer for beginners, but I think the OP was going for an **actual** **diy** Color-Picker, one that you wouldn't have to click to open a new window, and one that would not look so bland.(The `<input type="color">` is very, very bland and disgusting..)

Comment: @MohammedShareefC According to https://caniuse.com/input-color it works on all modern browsers.

Comment: @DonaldDuck . Happy to hear, although a few years later

Answer (score 8):

In addition for answer of [Gil Epshtain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2658683/gil-epshtain), if you do not wanna load an image you can fill the canvas with gradients

```js
function initColorPicker() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('colorCanvas');
  var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

  let gradient = canvas.getContext('2d').createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, 0)
  gradient.addColorStop(0, '#ff0000')
  gradient.addColorStop(1 / 6, '#ffff00')
  gradient.addColorStop((1 / 6) * 2, '#00ff00')
  gradient.addColorStop((1 / 6) * 3, '#00ffff')
  gradient.addColorStop((1 / 6) * 4, '#0000ff')
  gradient.addColorStop((1 / 6) * 5, '#ff00ff')
  gradient.addColorStop(1, '#ff0000')
  canvas.getContext('2d').fillStyle = gradient
  canvas.getContext('2d').fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

  gradient = canvas.getContext('2d').createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canvas.height)
  gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)')
  gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)')
  gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)')
  canvas.getContext('2d').fillStyle = gradient
  canvas.getContext('2d').fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

  gradient = canvas.getContext('2d').createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canvas.height)
  gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)')
  gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)')
  gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)')
  canvas.getContext('2d').fillStyle = gradient
  canvas.getContext('2d').fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)


  canvas.onclick = function(e) {
   console.log()
    var imgData = canvasContext.getImageData((e.offsetX / canvas.clientWidth) * canvas.width, (e.offsetY / canvas.clientHeight) * canvas.height, 1, 1)
    var rgba = imgData.data;
    var color = "rgba(" + rgba[0] + ", " + rgba[1] + ", " + rgba[2] + ", " + rgba[3] + ")";
    console.log("%c" + color, "color:" + color)
  }
}

initColorPicker()
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <canvas id="colorCanvas" class="color-canvas" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a color picker by  with type as color. But it works only in modern browsers.

DON'T USE Color Picker. It is ultra random as to what it does, older browsers turn it into a regular input, newer ones are random as it gets. Your best bet is to do as I am and either pick a Javascript color picker or create your own. I am forced to create my own because all of the current pickers are too project specific.

Comment: Most modern browsers won't support it.. Though, the current browser I am using is Mozilla Firefox, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```html
<input name="clr" type="color">
```

Answer (score 0):

### type="color" way

basically html has an many types for input
like button and checkbox
We can use the color type

```html
<input id="idHere" type="color">
<button onclick="alert(document.getElementById('idHere').value)">color value</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.