# HTML canvas element not displaying image

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I was trying to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40253697/how-to-create-a-color-picker-in-html/40253949) tutorial to make a color picker. I am not very familiar with the canvas element, so I am just testing with the code from that link. I set the image src with a few different images, and none of them are appearing.

I'm not sure what i'd have to change to make it appear, but I tried changing the src, and that is not the problem. Basically when you click on the color wheel (the image on the canvas) an alert should pop up with the rgba value.

If I had to guess, maybe the problem is here? I would think you need an src before telling it what to do when it loads.

```
image.onload = () => canvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
image.src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/flqeC.jpg?s=256";
```

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/zj8q5ngh/) is a jsfiddle with the code I have. I'm not the most experienced so this may be silly fix, but I appreciate any help!

Comment: You have to call your `initColorPicker()` method, but since you are using image from a different domain, `getImageData()` will not work. Try downloading the image to your local server and reference it from there.

Answer (score 1):

In local its working fine here is full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color: red;
            }

            #colorCanvas {
                border: 1px solid #000000;
                background-color:blue
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <canvas id="colorCanvas" class="color-canvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initColorPicker() {
            var canvasEl = document.getElementById('colorCanvas');
            var canvasContext = canvasEl.getContext('2d');

            var image = new Image(250, 250);

            image.onload = () => canvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
            image.src =  "http://localhost/test/assets/img/color.jpg";

            canvasEl.addEventListener('click', function (mouseEvent) {
                {
                    var imgData = canvasContext.getImageData(mouseEvent.offsetX, mouseEvent.offsetY, 1, 1);
                    var rgba = imgData.data;

                    alert("rgba(" + rgba[0] + ", " + rgba[1] + ", " + rgba[2] + ", " + rgba[3] + ")");
                }

            })
        }

        initColorPicker();
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: just copy the whole code and run it will show an alert

Answer (score 0):

Use Local Path of Image save that image in your local server otherwise you will get cross origin issue and then use this code

```
 function initColorPicker()
    {
        var canvasEl = document.getElementById('colorCanvas');
        var canvasContext = canvasEl.getContext('2d');

        var image = new Image(250, 250);

        image.onload = () => canvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
        image.src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/flqeC.jpg?s=256";

        canvasEl.addEventListener('click', function(mouseEvent) {
        {
          var imgData = canvasContext.getImageData(mouseEvent.offsetX, mouseEvent.offsetY, 1, 1);
          var rgba = imgData.data;

          alert("rgba(" + rgba[0] + ", " + rgba[1] + ", " + rgba[2] + ", " + rgba[3] + ")");
        }

    })
    }
    initColorPicker();
```

Comment: OP will still not get the values in `alert`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava check above code just modified , use addEventListener and use local path of your image

Comment: I switched it to the local path but I'm still not seeing anything, I checked that the path was right but nothing pops up in the canvas