# customise color picker with out any package in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RFki.png) [here is the design can we able to implement color picker like this without any packages in react](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yloS2.png)

is it possible to customize a color picker like the above image with react(without any package)? I tried a lot, but cannot able to find the proper solution. if anyone can help thanks in advance.

click this image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RFki.png [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yloS2.png need like this design]

Comment: It is possible. What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is the solution for my question also you can run this solution on code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-color-picker-component-forked-ltw23).

thanks, everyone :)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import "./styles.css";

const Container = styled.span`
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #bfc9d9;
  border-radius: 4px;

  input[type="color"] {
    margin-right: 8px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: none;
    &::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
      padding: 0;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
    }
    &::-webkit-color-swatch {
      border: 1px solid #bfc9d9;
      border-radius: 50px;
      padding: 0;
    }
  }

  input[type="text"] {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
`;

const ColorPicker = props => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <input type="color" {...props} />
      <input type="text" {...props} />
    </Container>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [state, updateState] = useState("#FFFFFF");

  const handleInput = e => {
    updateState(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ColorPicker onChange={handleInput} value={state} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use inbuilt developer tools in a browser

Comment: just look for chrome color picker extension from chrome web store

Answer (score 1):

[You can use html  tag of type 'color' as shown here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color)
If that does not work for you, you are looking at writing the color picker logic yourself.

```html
<div>
    <input type="color" id="head" name="head"
           value="#e66465">
    <label for="head">HTML 'color' input</label>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40253697/how-to-create-a-color-picker-in-html 
Have a look at this

Comment: no https://i.stack.imgur.com/yloS2.png please take look at this

Comment: what do you want to be able to do ? I don't understand what I am supposed to be looking for in that image.

Comment: i can able to implement the color picker what is need is color picker with border radius 100% is not working properly. the outer border only getting like circle shape. i need color to be has border-radius 100% and need display the hex value instead of RGB value. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RFki.png.