# I need to create a color picker but I dont know how to add it to my code

Tags: javascript, html

There is both the html and the javascript code here I dont know how to finish the colorPicker function in the javascript code. There are comments along the way explaining most of the code please try and show or tell me how to fix my colorChange function so that the user can pick a custom color that they so want.

```
    <head>
        <title>TicTacToe</title>
        <style>
          table, th, td {
            border: 3px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            }
    
          table.center {
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }
            body {
              background-image: url("./Story1-Page+BoardSetup/src/resources/bg.jpg");
              background-size: 100% 100%;
            }
    
    
    
        </style>
    </head>
    
    
    <body>
      <p align='center'><input id="play" type="button" value="Start a game" /></p>
      <p align='center'><input id="p1" type="button" value="Player 1 Settings" /></p>
      <p align='center'><input id="p2" type="button" value="Player 2 Settings" /></p>
      <p id="message" align='center'></p>
    
      <table style="width:700px" class = "center">
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align:center"> <input id="b1" type="button" style="width: 230px; font-size:200px; visibility: hidden" value="" onclick="setValue(this.id)" /></td>
          <td style="text-align:center"> <input id="b2" type="button" style="width: 230px; font-size:200px; visibility: hidden" value="" width="700" height="700" onclick="setValue(this.id)" /></td>
          <td style="text-align:center"> <input id="b3" type="button" style="width: 230px; font-size:200px; visibility: hidden" value="" width="700" height="700" onclick="setValue(this.id)" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align:center"> <input id="b4" type="button" style="width: 230px; font-size:200px; visibility: hidden" value="" width="700" height="700" onclick="setValue(this.id)" /></td>
          <td style="text-align:center"> <input id="b5" type="button" style="width: 230px; font-size:200px; visibility: hidden" value="" width="700" height="700" onclick="setValue(this.id)" /></td>
          <td style="text-align:center"> <input id="b6" type="button" style="width: 230px; font-size:200px; visibility: hidden" value="" width="700" height="700" onclick="setValue(this.id)" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align:center"> <input id="b7" type="button" style="width: 230px; font-size:200px; visibility: hidden" value="" width="700" height="700" onclick="setValue(this.id)" /></td>
          <td style="text-align:center"> <input id="b8" type="button" style="width: 230px; font-size:200px; visibility: hidden" value="" width="700" height="700" onclick="setValue(this.id)" /></td>
          <td style="text-align:center"> <input id="b9" type="button" style="width: 230px; font-size:200px; visibility: hidden" value="" width="700" height="700" onclick="setValue(this.id)" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    
      <script src="./Story1-Page+BoardSetup/src/tictactoe.js"></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
    


    var startBtn = document.getElementById("play");
    var p1 = document.getElementById("p1");
    p1.addEventListener("click", p1Menu);
    var p2 = document.getElementById("p2");
    p2.addEventListener("click", p2Menu);
    
    var backBtn = document.createElement("Button");
    backBtn.innerHTML = "Back";
    
    var confirmBtn = document.createElement("Button");
    confirmBtn.innerHTML = "Confirm";
    
    var gameBoard = [3];
    
    var gameInProgress = 0;//Checks if a game has started yet
    
    var player1 = { username: "Player 1", gameToken: 'X', color: "blue" };
    var player2 = { username: "Player 2", gameToken: 'O', color: "red" };
    
    var playerTurn = 1;
    
    var piecePlace = new sound("./Story1-Page+BoardSetup/src/resources/piecePlace.mp3");
    var gameStartSound = new sound("./Story1-Page+BoardSetup/src/resources/gameStart.wav");
    var gameWinSound = new sound("./Story1-Page+BoardSetup/src/resources/gameWin.wav");
    
    
    //Creates a simple message to display relevant information to the players
    var message = document.getElementById("message");
    message.innerHTML = "Welcome to our Tic-tac-toe game!";
    
    function resetGame() {
        //Resets the game board
        gameBoard = [3];
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            gameBoard[i] = new Array(3);//Creates array of size 3 in each spot of gameboard
        }
    
        var gridCount = 1;//Used for the grid IDs
    
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                var name = "b" + gridCount;//Used to get the ID names
                gameBoard[i][j] = "-";
                document.getElementById(name).value = "-";//Resets and sets up value
                document.getElementById(name).style.background = "white";//Resets bg color
                document.getElementById(name).style.visibility = "visible";
                gridCount++;
            }
        }
    
        gameInProgress = 1;//Pieces can now be placed
        playerTurn = 1;//Starts back at Player 1
        message.innerHTML = player1.username + " may now begin the game";
        console.log(gameBoard);
    }
    
    
    function updateGameBoard() {
        var count = 1;//Used for the grid IDs
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                var name = "b" + count;//Used for the grid ID names
                gameBoard[i][j] = document.getElementById(name).value//Gets values in game board
                count++;
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    function checkForWin() {
        let boardFull = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < gameBoard[0].length; j++) {
                if (gameBoard[i][j] == '-') {
                    boardFull = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    
        /*if(gameBoard[0][0] == gameBoard[0][1] && gameBoard[0][2] == gameBoard[0][1] && (gameBoard[0][0] != '-') ){
            document.getElementById("play").value="Play Again";
            alert("Player " + gameBoard[0][0] + " won!!");
            gameInProgress = 0;
            message.innerHTML="Game ended in a win for " + gameBoard[0][0];
        }
        else if(gameBoard[1][0] == gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[1][2] == gameBoard[1][1] && (gameBoard[1][0] != '-')){
            document.getElementById("play").value="Play Again";
            alert("Player " + gameBoard[1][0] + " won!!");
            gameInProgress = 0;
            message.innerHTML="Game ended in a win for " + gameBoard[1][0];
        }
        else if(gameBoard[2][0] == gameBoard[2][1] && gameBoard[2][2] == gameBoard[2][1] && (gameBoard[2][0] != '-')){
            document.getElementById("play").value="Play Again";
            alert("Player " + gameBoard[2][0] + " won!!");
            gameInProgress = 0;
            message.innerHTML="Game ended in a win for " + gameBoard[2][0];
        }
        else if(gameBoard[0][0] == gameBoard[1][0] && gameBoard[2][0] == gameBoard[1][0] && (gameBoard[0][0] != '-')){
            document.getElementById("play").value="Play Again";
            alert("Player " + gameBoard[0][0] + " won!!");
            gameInProgress = 0;
            message.innerHTML="Game ended in a win for " + gameBoard[0][0];
        }
        else if(gameBoard[0][1] == gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[2][1] == gameBoard[1][1] && (gameBoard[0][1] != '-')){
            document.getElementById("play").value="Play Again";
            alert("Player " + gameBoard[0][1] + " won!!");
            gameInProgress = 0;
            message.innerHTML="Game ended in a win for " + gameBoard[0][1];
        }
        else if(gameBoard[0][2] == gameBoard[1][2] && gameBoard[2][2] == gameBoard[1][2] && (gameBoard[0][2] != '-')){
            document.getElementById("play").value="Play Again";
            alert("Player " + gameBoard[0][2] + " won!!");
            gameInProgress = 0;
            message.innerHTML="Game ended in a win for " + gameBoard[0][2];
        }
        else if(gameBoard[0][0] == gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[2][2] == gameBoard[1][1] && (gameBoard[0][0] != '-')){
            document.getElementById("play").value="Play Again";
            alert("Player " + gameBoard[0][0] + " won!!");
            gameInProgress = 0;
            message.innerHTML="Game ended in a win for " + gameBoard[0][0];
        }
        else if(gameBoard[0][2] == gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[2][0] == gameBoard[1][1] && (gameBoard[0][2] != '-')){
            document.getElementById("play").value="Play Again";
            alert("Player " + gameBoard[0][0] + " won!!");
            gameInProgress = 0;
            message.innerHTML="Game ended in a win for " + gameBoard[0][2];
        }*/
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (gameBoard[i][0] == gameBoard[i][1] && gameBoard[i][0] == gameBoard[i][2] && gameBoard[i][1] == gameBoard[i][2] && gameBoard[i][0] != "-" && gameBoard[i][1] != "-" && gameBoard[i][2] != "-") {
                gameWinSound.play();
    
                if (gameBoard[i][0] == player1.gameToken) {
                    message.innerHTML = player1.username + " Wins!";
                    document.getElementById("play").value = "New Game";
                    alert(player1.username + " (" + player1.gameToken + ")" + " won!!");
                }
                else {
                    message.innerHTML = player2.username + " Wins!";
                    document.getElementById("play").value = "New Game";
                    alert(player2.username + " (" + player2.gameToken + ")" + " won!!");
                }
    
                gameInProgress = 0;
            }
            else if (gameBoard[0][i] == gameBoard[1][i] && gameBoard[0][i] == gameBoard[2][i] && gameBoard[1][i] == gameBoard[2][i] && gameBoard[0][i] != "-" && gameBoard[1][i] != "-" && gameBoard[2][i] != "-") {
                gameWinSound.play();
    
                if (gameBoard[0][i] == player1.gameToken) {
                    message.innerHTML = player1.username + " Wins!";
                    document.getElementById("play").value = "New Game";
                    alert(player1.username + " (" + player1.gameToken + ")" + " won!!");
                }
                else {
                    message.innerHTML = player2.username + " Wins!";
                    document.getElementById("play").value = "New Game";
                    alert(player2.username + " (" + player2.gameToken + ")" + " won!!");
                }
    
                gameInProgress = 0;
            }
    
        }
    
        if (gameBoard[0][0] == gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[0][0] == gameBoard[2][2] && gameBoard[1][1] == gameBoard[2][2] && gameBoard[0][0] != "-" && gameBoard[1][1] != "-" && gameBoard[2][2] != "-") {
            gameWinSound.play();
    
            if (gameBoard[0][0] == player1.gameToken) {
                message.innerHTML = player1.username + " Wins!";
                document.getElementById("play").value = "New Game";
                alert(player1.username + " (" + player1.gameToken + ")" + " won!!");
            }
            else {
                message.innerHTML = player2.username + " Wins!";
                document.getElementById("play").value = "New Game";
                alert(player2.username + " (" + player2.gameToken + ")" + " won!!");
            }
    
            gameInProgress = 0;
        }
        else if (gameBoard[0][2] == gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[0][2] == gameBoard[2][0] && gameBoard[1][1] == gameBoard[2][0] && gameBoard[0][2] != "-" && gameBoard[1][1] != "-" && gameBoard[2][0] != "-") {
            gameWinSound.play();
    
            if (gameBoard[0][2] == player1.gameToken) {
                message.innerHTML = player1.username + " Wins!";
                document.getElementById("play").value = "New Game";
                alert(player1.username + " (" + player1.gameToken + ")" + " won!!");
            }
            else {
                message.innerHTML = player2.username + " Wins!";
                document.getElementById("play").value = "New Game";
                alert(player2.username + " (" + player2.gameToken + ")" + " won!!");
            }
    
            gameInProgress = 0;
        }
        else if (boardFull && gameInProgress == 1)//Needs the gameInProgress or else will say someone won, and a tie on full board
        {
            alert("Tie game");
            message.innerHTML = "Game ended in a tie";
            document.getElementById("play").value = "New Game";
            gameInProgress = 0;
        }
    }
    
    function setValue(id) {
        if (document.getElementById(id).value == "-" && gameInProgress == 1) {
            if (playerTurn == 1) {
                document.getElementById(id).value = player1.gameToken;
                document.getElementById(id).style.background = player1.color;
                piecePlace.play();
                playerTurn++;
                message.innerHTML = player2.username + "'s turn";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById(id).value = player2.gameToken;
                document.getElementById(id).style.background = player2.color;
                piecePlace.play();
                playerTurn--;
                message.innerHTML = player1.username + "'s turn";
            }
    
            updateGameBoard();
            checkForWin();
        }
    
        else if (gameInProgress == 1) {
            if (playerTurn == 1) {
                message.innerHTML = player1.username + "'s turn, selected spot is already occupied";
            }
            else {
                message.innerHTML = player2.username + "'s turn, selected spot is already occupied";
            }
        }
    }
    
    startBtn.onclick = function startGame() {
        document.getElementById("play").value = "Reset Game";
        gameStartSound.play();
        resetGame();//Ensure game board is set-up
    }
    
    /*
     * Displays the settings menu for p1
     */
    function p1Menu() {
        message.innerHTML = player1.username + "'s piece: " + player1.gameToken.fontcolor(player1.color) + " ";
        settingsButtons(1);
    }
    
    /*
     * Displays the settings menu for p2
     */
    function p2Menu() {
        message.innerHTML = player2.username + "'s piece: " + player2.gameToken.fontcolor(player2.color) + " ";
        settingsButtons(2);
    }
    
    /*
     * Adds the settings buttons to either player's menu
     */
    function settingsButtons(turn) {
        var changeNameBtn = document.createElement("Button");
        changeNameBtn.innerHTML = "Change Username";
        changeNameBtn.onclick = function () { changeNameMenu(turn); }
    
        var changePieceBtn = document.createElement("Button");
        changePieceBtn.innerHTML = "Change Game Piece";
        changePieceBtn.onclick = function () { changePieceMenu(turn); }
    
        var changeColorBtn = document.createElement("Button");
        changeColorBtn.innerHTML = "Change Piece Color";
    
        message.appendChild(changeNameBtn);
        message.appendChild(changePieceBtn);
        message.appendChild(changeColorBtn);
    }

function colorChange(turn){
    
    message.innerHTML = "Pick your new Color and click Confirm";
    message.prepend(backBtn);

    var changeColorBtn = document.createElement("INPUT");



}

    
    
    
    /*
     * Handles the menu for when a player attempts to change their username
     */
    function changeNameMenu(turn) {
        message.innerHTML = " Enter your new Username in the box and click Confirm: ";
    
        message.prepend(backBtn);
    
        var changeNameText = document.createElement("INPUT");
        changeNameText.setAttribute("type", "text");
    
        message.appendChild(changeNameText);
        message.appendChild(confirmBtn);
    
        if (turn == 1) {
            backBtn.onclick = function () { p1Menu(); }
            changeNameText.defaultValue = player1.username;
            confirmBtn.onclick = function () {
                if (changeNameText.value == "SecretGame") {
                    window.location.replace("./Story1-Page+BoardSetup/src/resources/picross.html");
                }
    
                player1.username = changeNameText.value;
                p1Menu();
            }
        }
        else if (turn == 2) {
            backBtn.onclick = function () { p2Menu(); }
            changeNameText.defaultValue = player2.username;
            confirmBtn.onclick = function () {
                player2.username = changeNameText.value;
                p2Menu();
            }
        }
    }
    
    /*
     * Handles the menu for when a player attempts to change their game piece
     */
    function changePieceMenu(turn) {
        message.innerHTML = " Enter your new game token in the box and click Confirm: ";
    
        message.prepend(backBtn);
    
        var changePieceText = document.createElement("INPUT");
        changePieceText.setAttribute("type", "text");
        changePieceText.setAttribute("maxlength", "1");
        changePieceText.setAttribute("size", "1");
    
        message.appendChild(changePieceText);
        message.appendChild(confirmBtn);
    
        if (turn == 1) {
            backBtn.onclick = function () { p1Menu(); }
            changePieceText.defaultValue = player1.gameToken;
            confirmBtn.onclick = function () {
    
                if (changePieceText.value != player2.gameToken) {
                    player1.gameToken = changePieceText.value;
    
                    gridCount = 1; //Used for the grid IDs
                    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                            //Checks if each tile isn't the other player's token or the default token
                            if (gameBoard[i][j] != player2.gameToken && gameBoard[i][j] != "-") {
                                //If it passes the above if, it must be the current player's old token
                                var name = "b" + gridCount;
                                //Set the old token to the new one
                                gameBoard[i][j] = player1.gameToken;
                                document.getElementById(name).value = player1.gameToken;
                            }
                            gridCount++;
                        }
                    }
                    p1Menu();
    
                }
                else {
                    alert("The token you entered matches that of the other player");
                }
            }
        }
        else if (turn == 2) {
            backBtn.onclick = function () { p2Menu(); }
            changePieceText.defaultValue = player2.gameToken;
            confirmBtn.onclick = function () {
    
                if (changePieceText.value != player1.gameToken) {
                    player2.gameToken = changePieceText.value;
    
                    gridCount = 1; //Used for the grid IDs
                    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                            //Checks if each tile isn't the other player's token or the default token
                            if (gameBoard[i][j] != player1.gameToken && gameBoard[i][j] != "-") {
                                //If it passes the above if, it must be the current player's old token
                                var name = "b" + gridCount;
                                //Set the old token to the new one
                                gameBoard[i][j] = player2.gameToken;
                                document.getElementById(name).value = player2.gameToken;
                            }
                            gridCount++;
                        }
                    }
                    p2Menu();
                }
                else {
                    alert("The token you entered matches that of the other player");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    function sound(src) {
        this.sound = document.createElement("audio");
        this.sound.src = src;
        this.sound.setAttribute("preload", "auto");
        this.sound.setAttribute("controls", "none");
        this.sound.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(this.sound);
    
        this.play = function () {
            this.sound.play();
        }
    
        this.stop = function () {
            this.sound.pause();
        }
    }
    
    //Exports information from this file for use in our test file
    try {
        module.exports.resetGame = resetGame;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log('error with module.exports!');
    }
```

Comment: Please search on stackoverflow before you add a new question - for example here is one of them: [how-to-create-a-color-picker-in-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40253697/how-to-create-a-color-picker-in-html)...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a color picker in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40253697/how-to-create-a-color-picker-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`<input type="color">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color)